# Return indexes of list in same order as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following list:

```
inputList = [5, 2, 1]
```

which corresponds to the indexes in another dataframe

```
[4,1,0]
```

However, to get the indexes I always get the sorted indexes (`[0,1,4]`), not the `inputList` index order:

```
idx = [df['id'].isin(map(str,sorted(inputList)))].index.tolist()
```

How can I get it?

Comment: Can you explain why you call `sorted` when you don't want to have it sorted?

Comment: Thanks!!! I am using some code I wrote in another script..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `inputList = [5, 2, 1]` matches the indexes `[4, 1, 0]`, it is not surprising that `sorted(inputList)` (which is `[1, 2, 5]`) matches the indexes `[0, 1, 4]`.

Try without `sorted`:

```
idx = [df['id'].isin(map(str, inputList))].index.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it does not work. Still getting it sorted..

Comment: Not sure, but what if `index` necessarily produced a sorted list? Also, what would you expect to get if you had several occurrences of the values from your `inputList`? I am afraid you need to use something more complex than `isin` to get the expected output.